# Customizing datatable's pagination when using data source as ajax

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using ajax as datatable source with Laravel as backend API server. Laravel has it's own library class to manage paginations and datatable has it's front end pagination feature as well. Since I am working on Restful API web services, so i don't want to have paginations to be handled by Laravel as that will make api to be tightly coupled with front end systems.

Datatable has got it's own pagination feature too, so the resource controller will serve only recordset, total rows count with additional parameters such as offset and limit that will be requested by ajax call.

But I could not find any documentation/tutorials regarding datatable based paginations. Any idea?

Comment: If the API can't handle paging, then the full result set would be retrieved and returned for every request, and the consumer would be responsible for paging. This probably isn't what you're looking for. In any event, if you're using datatables and Laravel, you may want to check out the [bllim/laravel4-datatables-package](https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package) package.

Comment: @patricus, I don't want to use package at the moment. I would like to use the datatable pagination feature to handle my logic. But I couldn't find any resource that could help me to customize datatable pagination script.